# Implementing autofill for onlyfans login page with QWebEngine based app

Tags: c++, qt, autofill, qwebengineview

I'm trying to implement autofill functionality in a Qt Webengine based app.
My approach is based off Viper browser's [implementation](https://github.com/LeFroid/Viper-Browser/blob/master/src/core/autofill/AutoFill.cpp#L115): running script on page's `loadFinished` signal. The script run just looks up all the fields that can be populated and fills them as simple as `elem.value = 'value'`.

It works with simple example like e.g. my wifi router config page (which uses very simple logic for forms). But it doesn't work with e.g. https://onlyfans.com/ login page.
When I run my script I get JS errors like:

> "js: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null".

The minimal example demonstrating the issue:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QObject>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QWebEngineView>
#include <QWebEnginePage>
#include <QWebEngineProfile>
#include <QWebEngineScript>
#include <QWebEngineScriptCollection>

const char* URL_ONLYFANS = "https://onlyfans.com/";
const char* URL_ROUTER = "http://192.168.0.1/";

const char* SCRIPT_ROUTER(R"(
document.querySelector('input[type=text]').value = 'admin';
document.querySelector('input[type=password]').value = 'mypass';
)");

const char* SCRIPT_ONLYFANS(R"(
document.querySelector('input[name=email]').value = "random@gmail.com";
document.querySelector('input[name=password]').value = "randompass";
)");

class Observer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Observer(QWebEnginePage *page): _page(page)
    {}

public slots:
    void onPageLoad(bool ok)
    {
        qDebug() << "Page loaded" << ok;
        
        // Running script right away pretty much guarantees JS errors
        // No JS errors if delay is >= 1500 ms:
        QTimer::singleShot(1500, this, &Observer::runScript);
        qDebug() << "Scheduled running script";
    }

    void runScript()
    {
        _page->runJavaScript(SCRIPT_ONLYFANS);
        
        qDebug() << "Ran script";
    }

private:
    QWebEnginePage *_page{nullptr};
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QWebEngineView view;
    QWebEngineProfile profile;
    QWebEnginePage page(&profile);
    
    view.setPage(&page);
    view.setUrl(QUrl(URL_ONLYFANS));
    view.resize(1024, 750);

    Observer observer(view.page());

    QObject::connect(view.page(), &QWebEnginePage::loadFinished,
                     &observer, &Observer::onPageLoad);

/*
    {
        QWebEngineScript script;

        script.setName("autofill");
        script.setSourceCode(SCRIPT_ONLYFANS);
        
        // Also tried `DocumentCreation` and `Deferred`, didn't work for Onlyfans
        script.setInjectionPoint(QWebEngineScript::DocumentReady);
        script.setRunsOnSubFrames(true);
        script.setWorldId(QWebEngineScript::ApplicationWorld);
        view.page()->scripts().insert(script);
    }
*/

    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

As can be seen I tried to insert my scripts in two ways: on page's `loadFinished` signal (both immediately and with a time delay) and by inserting my script into page's scripts collection. I tried all available insertion points: `DocumentCreation`, `DocumentReady` and `Deferred`.

In all cases I get JS error shown above. Except for the case when I delay script execution by about 1500 ms, which is obviously a guess and is not robust.

I do understand that the elements I'm trying to set are probably not yet created, so I'd like some advice on how to properly time the script execution.

Comment: onlyfans, hmmm.  What are you trying to do there exactly?

Comment: Autofill login and password fields so that user can just press LOGIN button and proceed. Onlyfans is just a an example of non-trivial login form.